# mininet connect to remote ODL controller with python code

Tags: sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I'm new to mininet, I want to see the network topology using opendaylight(carbon) controller. I have tried command:

```
sudo mn --topo linear,3 --mac \
    --controller=remote,ip=10.109.253.152,port=6633 \
    --switch ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13,stp=1
```

And the opendaylight can successfully show the whole topology. And Then, I want to show the same result by using python code solely. However, it doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import RemoteController, OVSSwitch
from mininet.log import info, setLogLevel
from mininet.cli import CLI

def RemoteCon():
    net = Mininet(controller=RemoteController, switch=OVSSwitch)

    c1 = net.addController('c1', ip='10.109.253.152',port=6633)
    h1 = net.addHost('h1')
    h2 = net.addHost('h2')
    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')
    net.addLink(s1, h1)
    net.addLink(s1, h2)

    net.build()
    net.start()

    CLI(net)

    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    RemoteCon()
```

Oh, by the way, does the switches have default forwarding functionality? Sometimes, I have hosts and switch connected to each other and hosts can ping each other while running above code, h1 cannot ping h2 and vice versa.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the l2switch feature in OpenDaylight.

if you search this forum, you'll find others complaining of inconsistent
connectivity when using l2switch. You are probably hitting bugs, but
after a restart of OpenDaylight, it might be ok. By default, with l2switch
it should learn the links of the topology, and create the flows to allow
all hosts to ping every other host.

as for your python script to run mininet, I don't see anything obvious.
Can you look in the OpenDaylight karaf.log for any clues? Or check the
OVS logs for other clues? If you are just simply not seeing anything
in the topology viewer, then my guess is that the OVS is not connecting
to OpenDaylight at all.

One thing to double check. I don't know how the python script is deciding
which openflow version to use, but maybe it's using 1.0 and that's the
big difference from your command line, which sets it to 1.3?

Comment: Thanks, jamo. ovs logs shown below: `record 656: 2018-04-11 07:57:55.011 "ovs-vsctl (invoked by bash): ovs-vsctl -- --id=@s1c1 create Controller "target=\"tcp:10.109.253.152:6633\"" max_backoff=1000 -- --if-exists del-br s1 -- add-br s1 -- set bridge s1 controller=[@s1c1] other_config:datapath-id=0000000000000001 fail_mode=secure other-config:disable-in-band=true other-config:dp-desc=s1 -- add-port s1 s1-eth1 -- set Interface s1-eth1 ofport_request=1 -- add-port s1 s1-eth2 -- set Interface s1-eth2 ofport_request=2"`

Comment: Since I can see network topo using mn command, I think l2switch is enabled in ODL. And I have tried restart ODL, it still can not show any topology.

Comment: I have tried openfloodlight controller, I can successfully show my topology after running my python script. It's definitely a bug of ODL. Thanks jamo.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you missed starting your switch to communicate with the controller. Try

```
s1.start([c1])
```

This defines which controller the switch is connected to. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should give protocols parameter to addSwitch function as command line:

```
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1',switch=OVSSwitch,protocols='OpenFlow10')
```